# Query Editor: How to create a query on the backlog as it was on a specific date?

Tags: charts, azure-devops, cumulative-sum

The Cumulative Flow Diagram is useful, but its granularity is set quite large, i.e. you can only see numbers for the dates it chooses, which can be a week or more apart.  However, it shows that under the hood, VSTS is recording the state of the backlog at every date.

It seems that the data must exist to find out the data I need (in this case the sum of effort for each state for PBIs) as it was at a given date - not just the dates picked by the chart for its points.

I've searched around but can't find it anywhere.  Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Cumulative Flow Diagrams (CFD) can be shown in Kanban board or dashboard (you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/cumulative-flow?view=vsts). You can specify the date as you need, but it has no business with query. So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: That would work.  All I need (in this instance) is a means to know, for a specific date in the past, how many points were in the backlog of each state and with a few filters set on tags.  It's so I can keep track of trends even when the goalposts move in terms of the filters.

Comment: I've not been able to find a means to specify a date, so if you can point me to that I'd be very grateful.

Comment: The CFD show the cumulative things during a past point to present. So want you can specify is only for the one past date. Is it what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that would do it.  I need to backdate our own projection analyses when the criteria have changed, which means looking at the figures for previous sprint transition dates.

Comment: (I don't mind doing this manually a date at a time - it's not a regular task)

Comment: I added an answer for detail steps, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

**To set date for Cumulative Flow Diagrams (CFD)**, you just need to click on the CFD and edit the date.

Such as to set the date of the CFD in backlog:

Click the diagram -> Edit -> specify the start date in Cumulative flow Tab -> Save.

[image]

Then the CFD will be changed based on the specified period.

**To filter CFD by tag, type, Assign To etc**, VSTS has not support this feature for now. But you can create an  [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) for it, or you can calculate with your own code.

Comment: Ah - I think I've just realised where I may be asking a bit more than TS supports.  The CFD I'm using isn't the out-of-the-box one; it's one I've created based on a query that includes only a subset of the backlog.  If I use the standard CFD it won't let me filter the backlog or change the source to a query that filters the backlog.  Is there any way to have it both ways, i.e. specify a date but also filter the scope of the data it's including by (in this case) tags?

Comment: @JoelTeague How did you create a CFD based on a query? Can you show the related screen shots?

Comment: For some reason this isn't letting me add a screenshot so I'll do my best to explain.  I set this up a while back, and looking at it it's a ground-up reconstruction of a CFD based on a stacked area chart, aggregated on the sum off effort by state, and drawing on a query of my backlog, filtered to certain tags.  It chooses its own dates, but appears to be able to know what the sum of effort for each state was on that date.  All I need to be able to do is dictate the date - but unfortunately that option only seems to occur if you use the standard CFD, which doesn't let you filter by tags.

Comment: No, CFD can be only specified with the date not filters (by tag, type, Assign To etc). The filters in backlog is used to show certain work items clearly, but it has no effect on CFD.

Comment: So it can't be done, then?  It's a problem because the history logic in the chart I've created seems to have some big issues - to the point where we have to largely ignore it and live without reliable trends data.

Comment: Yes, VSTS has no such settings to achieve it. But you can calculate by your own code, or you can create an user voice (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) to suggest the feature.

Comment: Thanks; I think that's where I'm at.  It's a big hole in the functionality, so I'll probably do both.

Comment: If the answer helps you for the question you asked, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions :)